# Trying to get the specific information from the array

Tags: bash

I need to convert this array:

```
arr=("aa:" "info" "{" "bb:" "name" "value" "50;" "bb:" "surname" "oth_value" "50;" "bb:" "age" "number" "3;" "bb:" "about" "text" "void;" "}")
```

to something like this:

```
arr=(("aa:" "info" "{") ("bb:" "name" "value" "50;") ("bb:" "surname" "oth_value" "50;") ("bb:" "age" "number" "3;") ("bb:" "about" "text" "void;") ("}"))
```

the goal is to loop through the multidimensional array to be able to perform actions with each array that is inside. For example:

```
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
   echo "${arr[i][0]}"
   # prints out the first value of each element
   echo "${arr[i][1]}"
   # prints out the second value of each element
done
```

What I need is to be able to separate the information between `bb:` and `;` and use each of it's elements. For example to echo it out. The only idea I came up with is to put separate the needed information in the arrays inside of the main array (to create multidimensional) and when looping through it, to use the values I need. Basically there will be only three values between `bb:` and `;`. But the number of this `bb:` and `;` sections is unlimited. The `aa: info {` and the `}` should be cutted of. I don't need them.

Comment: Bash doesn't have multidimensional arrays (though of course you can fake them). It's also not at all well suited for parsing; do you really need to use a shell script for this?

Comment: @MichaelHomer Yes I need to use shell scripting. I am writing a program in bash right now and it is part of it. I thought to convert the array to string and than split it into array by delimiters, but couldn't make it work properly.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be part of it, then. Use a proper language with a parsing library and have the script call out to your new subprogram, if that's at all an option.

Comment: That said, if it *really* has to be pure Bash, associative arrays can fake multiple dimensions, or if it's purely loop processing you can avoid the need to make the actual structure at all. It seems that you just want to get items in blocks of four if there's really no more complexity in the format.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Look, I started writing the script as an .sh file and I want it to be completely  in this file, without calling out other scripts from it. I will rewrite it to a proper language, but later. I appreciate your advice, but right now I need it to accomplish in the bash script. I have nothing against using perl or sed inside the script, if they will help somehow...

Comment: @MichaelHomer Yes I want to get the items in blocks by looping through. And actually blocks of three (I want to remove the bb: from each element (don't need it)). Do you have any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr=("aa:" "info" "{" "bb:" "name" "value" "50;" "bb:" "surname" "oth_value" "50;" "bb:" "age" "number" "3;" "bb:" "about" "text" "void;" "}")
for ((i=3; i + 4 < ${#arr[@]}; i+=4))
do
    echo "${arr[i]}"
    echo "${arr[i + 1]}"
    echo "${arr[i + 2]}"
    echo "${arr[i + 3]}"
done
```

This is a straightforward [C-style for loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-for). You can ignore any of the fields you don't want to care about, and change the numbers.

---

Wherever this array originally came from, you'd almost certainly be better off in general using a proper parser on the source text, but this does satisfy the scenario you've described adequately. As soon as it gets more complicated it's going to get much harder, though — it's only because it happens to be purely stepping by four that this works out simply.